# Is it possible to put calculation inside plotbands using highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I build line charts using highcharts library. In the highcharts I am using `plotBands`. Is it possible to put calculation inside `plotBands` like shown below?

`

```
plotBands: [{
                    from:{
                         formatter: function() {
                                 return Math.round(Math.log10(-10.0)); 
                        }},
                    to: {
                         formatter: function() {
                                 return Math.round(Math.log10(1.0)); 
                        }},,
                    color: '#00A19C'
                },
```

`

Comment: You will need to use a function that return a number before rendering the chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it using `IIFE`:

```
  yAxis: {
    plotBands: [{
      color: '#FCFFC5',
      from: (function() {
        return Math.round(Math.log10(-10.0)); 
      })(),
      to: (function() {
        return Math.round(Math.log10(1.0)); 
      })()
    }]
  }
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/056u7ob3/